# No logro importar módulos desde otro directorio en python

Tags: python

Tengo una carpeta que se llama `PracticaGUI`, en la cual hay tres carpetas: `Vistas`, `Modelo` y `Controlador`:,

```
PracticaGUI
    Controlador
       __init__
       metodosVentanas
    Vistas
       __init__
       vista1
    Modelo
       __init__
```

Quiero importar el módulo `metodosVentanas` que está en `Controlador` al módulo `vista1` que está en la carpeta `Vistas`, este es el código que tengo:

```
from tkinter import *
from Controlador.metodosVentanas import *
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jesus\Documents\Programacion\Python\PracticaGUI\Vistas\vista1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Controlador.metodosVentanas import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Controlador'
```

No entiendo, si `Controlador` no es el módulo, `Controlador` se supone es el paquete, y módulo sería mas bien `metodosVentanas`.

No entiendo por qué no importa, incluso hasta logra reconocer las llamadas al módulo `metodosVentanas`.

No logro importar `Controlador.metodosVentanas` al módulo que está en la carpeta `Vistas`, `vista1`.

Comment: Ponlo en una subcarpeta

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, aunque no está relacionado directamente con tu problema, decir que se desaconseja el uso de `import *`, pues puede causar colisión de nombres. Es mejor importar sólo los símbolos individuales que necesites. Y mejor aún importar el módulo y luego usar el nombre del módulo como *namespace*, es decir `modulo.funcion()`, pues hace más claro al leer el código el saber de qué módulo proviene cada símbolo.

Centrándonos ya en tu problema, lo que necesitas es un *import relativo*, es decir, dentro de `Vistas/vista.py` el import debería ser:

```
from ..Controlador.metodosVentanas import *
```

(insisto en que el `import *` se desaconseja, pero de momento lo dejo así porque desconozco qué símbolos contiene el módulo importado).

Como ves el truco es el `..` delante del nombre del módulo para indicar una especie de ruta relativa.

Para que esto funcione, la carpeta `PracticaGUI` debería ser un paquete, es decir, tener también un fichero `__init__.py` (aunque esté vacío). Tu script "principal" debería ejecutarse fuera de la carpeta `PracticaGUI`, e incluir el nombre de esa carpeta como nombre de paquete. Por ejemplo:

```
# programa "principal", situado encima de la carpeta PracticaGUI
from PracticaGUI.Vistas import vista1
...
```

### Minimo ejemplo verificable

Tengo la siguiente estructura de carpetas y ficheros:

```
.
├── PracticaGUI
│   ├── Controlador
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── metodosVentanas.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── Modelo
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── Vistas
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── vista1.py
└── principal.py
```

Todos los `__init__.py` están vacíos. El programa `principal.py` por el que todo arranca está *fuera de la carpeta `PracticaGUI`* y contiene lo siguiente:

```
# ./principal.py

# Importo el módulo vista1 del paquete PracticaGUI.Vistas
from PracticaGUI.Vistas import vista1

# Invoco la función `vista()` que está en ese módulo
vista1.vista()
```

En `PracticaGUI/Vistas/vista1.py` hay lo siguiente:

```
# ./PracticaGUI/Vistas/vista1.py
print("vista1 importado!")

from ..Controlador.metodosVentanas import ventana

def vista():
    print("Invocada función vista1.vista()")
    # Ejemplo de que puedo usar el metodo de otro modulo
    ventana()
```

Observa cómo se importa la función `ventana` desde el paquete `Controlador`, usando el import relativo. Una vez importada esa función puede usarse como se ve más abajo, en `ventana()`.

Finalmente, la implementación de `ventana()` está en:

```
# ./PracticaGUI/Controlador/metodosVentanas.py
print("metodosVentanas importado!")

# Ejemplo de símbolo para exportar
def ventana():
    print("Invocado metodosVentana.ventana()")
```

Al ejecutar el programa principal vemos que todo se importa correctamente:

```
$ python ./principal.py
vista1 importado!
metodosVentanas importado!
Invocada función vista1.vista()
Invocado metodosVentana.ventana()
```

Comment: No me funciona :(

Comment: A mi sí. Algo estás haciendo diferente. Acabo de editar la respuesta para añadir un minimo ejemplo verificable que puedas comparar con el tuyo.